# HTML table and Datatables allignment

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I have a razor view which HTML output is a table formatted with DataTables javascript plug-in to enhance it with fancy features as pagination, sorting, searching, etc..
My view looks like follows:

[image: My asp.net MVC app with Datatables]

Everything works like a charm, but as you can see, the search box and the pagination bar(marked in red) appears alligned to the very right of the page instead of close to the table itself(I want it in the green box).
Any idea to accomplish this?

Here is my Razor code:

[image]

I've tried with a container div for the table and a fixed width, as well as a fixed width for the table itself without success.

Help very appreciated!

Comment: please paste code, not a picture of code.  Also the code posted doesn't show any css or the secarch box / pagination in question

Comment: Is you table initially in a hidden div? If so take a look at this: http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs/

Comment: Thank you for your answer Pete:
-I pasted a picture as the editor was getting crazy with the formatting and was not readable at all
-The table is not in a hidden div: As Gyrocedo.dom said, the issue was with bootstrap and nothing to do DataTables at all (might be also solved with datatables dom parameter though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `width="100%"` attribute for `<table>` to make it occupy full width of the container. Since you're using Bootstrap framework, apply corresponding classes.

```
<table id="filesTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
```

See [Bootstrap 3 example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!! Indeed the issue was with bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Use the `dom` parameter to wrap the search box and pager into some `<div>`, then use CSS to align them how you want.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "dom": '<"top"f>t<"bottom"p>'
} );
```

will result in the following HTML

```
<div class="top">
    {filter}
</div>
    {table}
<div class="bottom">
    {pagination}
</div>
```

[DataTables Reference: dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)